# Does T-Mobile now throttle one's internet access when roaming?

Tags: mexico, roaming

I'm on an Go5G Plus with T-Mobile which is supposed to include a [generous roaming quot](https://www.t-mobile.com/support/coverage/international-roaming-services)a:

> Go5G, MAX and Plus plans give you up to 5GB of high-speed data in more than 215 countries and destinations at no extra charge. Go5G, Magenta, ONE, and Simple Choice plans give you up to 5GB of high-speed data in 11 European countries (Austria, Croatia, Czech Republic, Germany, Hungary, Poland, Slovakia, North Macedonia, Montenegro, Romania, and Greece) at no extra charge

However after I've arrived to Mexico this week I've noticed that my phone's internet speed is significantly throttled despite having had used far less than 5GB of data. One of my friends is on a different T-Mobile plan and their internet is likewise significantly throttled. However another friend is using an Airalo travel SIM and they're able to get **10x** higher speeds when connected to the exact same tower, the exact same wireless standard (LTE), the exact same location and the exact same type of phone. Being connected to 5G doesn't improve the speed either.

I'm well aware that roaming is usually slower due to all traffic being routed through one's home country but is T-Mobile now applying additional hidden throttling on top of that? The question is highly practical as I'll probably have to get a separate travel SIM if that's the case, rather than relying on my normal plan.

Comment: You say you're in Mexico, but quote about high speeds in European countries...

Comment: In my experience (which is considerable) tmobile doesn't throttle in Mexico. High speed in Mexico is included in most tmobile plans AFAIK, and we've only been throttled after hitting 5GB. We have always been notified many many times befitted we hit the cap and are slowed down

Comment: Did you run a speed test ? Services throttle for all types of legitimate or illegitimate reasons all the time.  Looking at the number is really the only way of telling what's happening. Sometimes opening a second window and running a "well known" speed tests app will significantly the speed in your first window (since the services know they are being measured).

Comment: My other comment not withstanding I'm a very happy T-Mobile (magenta) customer: I travel a lot data and text work everywhere as soon as I hit the ground or cross the border. Speeds vary all over the place for no discernable reasons but as long as Google Maps and WhatsApp work, I'm perfectly happy. For anything data intensive, I use WIFI (and plan for accordingly).

Comment: @Hilmar hit fast.com for both T mobile and Airalo. Huge difference.

Comment: I’ve noticed that phones sometimes have issues hopping back on the right band when coming back from roaming. I’ve seen my phone stuck on EDGE in such a case. Rebooting helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you'll ever get an official answer that says anything other than *"No, T-Mobile doesn't throttle while roaming,"* as anything else would contradict what they're offering (at least in the specified countries, which includes Mexico).

However, reading through the comments has prompted me to share my own experience.

1. T-Mobile hasn't been throttled for us, except for passing the 5GB cap.  And this has *always* been notified by text several times before the slow down.  I think the first text is at 80% (so 4GB).
2. Cellphone service in Mexico is not as consistent as in the US.  Different parts of urban areas can switch between LTE and 3G with no apparent reason.  We do not expect there to always be cellphone data available.
3. While on roaming (with US carrier) I have had my phone switch Mexican carrier, which has noticeably affected speeds and even signal strength (full-bars to 1-2 bars).  This is while in one location, not traveling.  I will often manually select a service provider to get more consistent signal and speed.
4. 5G coverage is very limited.  I don't believe I've ever connected to 5G in Mexico yet, but I know it's out there, somewhere...
5. When we cross the border, my phone (not T-Mobile) switches immediately to Mexican provider, while my wife's phone (T-Mobile) will almost always require a restart, otherwise it can take an hour or longer, sometimes next day, before she gets a proper connection again (and often she still restarts as there are still niggles that can't be explained).  This has happened with multiple different phones on her T-Mobile plan.
6. Telcel is the largest and, in our experience, most consistent provider in Mexico.  If you have signal trouble, try manually selecting TELCEL.

So in answer to your question, no T-Mobile doesn't throttle in Mexico.  But there could be a number of other factors that could be influencing your experience and getting a travel SIM may not directly solve it.  That said, getting a SIM in Mexico is relatively quick and cheap - $100 pesos will get you connected for ~10 days if you wanted to try it out.

Answer (score 4):

OK, this one's completely my fault, not T-Mobile. Turns out, by default they throttle **Fast.com** because it uses Netflix servers but other sites are not throttled. When checking the speed with SpeedTest instead, the results were very close to Airalo.

So the answer is: no, they don't throttle (beyond official roaming limits).

Note that you can disable Netflix throttling by going [to settings](https://my.t-mobile.com/account/profile/media_settings) and enabling "4K UHD Video":

[image]

Once this is done Fast.com will show your speed measurement correctly.

Comment: Does that mean that they throttle Netflix then?

Comment: @xngtng updated the answer

Comment: +1. Interesting, I didn't know Netflix 4K would change the results somehow, I guess they use different URLs or made the option otherwise detectable.